# Subdomain: Access Denied

Tags: subsites

I just enabled the Subdomain module but when I go to the subdomain url as a anonymous user I get this message:

> Access denied
>
> You are not authorized to access this page.

Update: I tried giving the anonymous visitor all permissions and the page showed. Now I started to disable permissions one by one till I found out which permission makes it possible for me to see the page and not get the acces denied message.
The permission I need to have enabled to get this to work is: **Administer site configuration**. Of course it's not possible to leave it like this...but maybe someone now knows what the problem could be.

Any suggestion on how to solve this or other things I can try?
Thanks

Comment: As per the question guidelines... narrow it down for us.  What have you already tried?

Comment: I edited my main post. Hope this is better like this.